# Force type="datetime-local" to act as type="text"

Tags: html, selenium, input

I want to override the default behavior of an input control.

I use `<input type="datetime-local">` and it works almost fine for the user, with a pretty calendar and all. But for automated tests it's a nightmare.

Is it possible to patch the browser such that `type="datetime-local"` act as a `type="text"`? I would enable this mode during tests and solve all my problems.

I think I need this to be on the browser level because such tags are generated dynamically all the time via vue.js so a one-time attribute replacement won't work. I use the latest chrome version.

### Update

I need to bypass the fancy data-editing that is almost-locale-dependant. If I can set the value of the control to `2018-06-12T19:30` I will be happy. This is actually the fallback behavior on browsers that don't support datetime-local.

This cannot be javascript based on a control by control basis, since the page is accessed via browser-driver and selenium.

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to do? fetch the datatime from that input?

Comment: I had a problem with the way my browser displayed input type="number" elements, so when the user left the element (blur), I changed the element to type="text" and this allowed me to change the class style applied to the element with better results.  So, in short, no, you can't change the browser's code with a patch, that truly would be a nightmare, but you can add javascript to work around the 'short-comings' of how element behave.  Of, course, you'll probably need to write your own validation, because in order to get out of the field you're going to need to bypass the date-time validation.

Comment: Alternatively, if the suggested answer, below doesn't help, then you could go with a plug-in that is more flexible in the dates and date formats it supports.  I had a problem, where  I needed to accept 'free-format' dates that the user typed in, i.e., mm-d(d)-yy(yy), dd-MMM-yy(yy), MMM(M...) d(d), yy(yy), and so on.  It took about a page of code to check the user's input against all of the variations.  In my case, I displayed a text input and offered the calendar as a pop-up.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trials and error (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in JS

```
 var d = document.getElementById("date").value;
 var n = d.toString();
```

And then use n

Comment: This won't work. I can read the value of the control fine in javascript. The problem is data-entry in the automated test. By disabling the behavior of datetime-local I can enter 2018-06-12T19:30 and forget about the dateformat/tab/timeformat am/pm etc.